# dragend on background stopPropagation does not work in Chrome 36

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, stoppropagation

consider this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vis"></div>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("#vis")
    .style({position: "fixed", width: "100%", height: "100%"})
    .append("svg")
    .style({margin: "3%", border: "1px solid #aaa"})
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 600")

svg.on("click", function (d, i) {
    console.log("click")
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented)
        return
    console.log("click fell through")
})

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0).attr("width", "50%").attr("height", "50%")
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("dragstart", function (d) {
            console.log("dragstart")
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation()
            // d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault()
        })
    )
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Start a drag on the rectangle and end the drag on the background. In Chrome 36, the background click is not suppressed and not prevented. This is not what I expect and not what Firefox 31 does. Can someone please explain the difference in browser behaviour and provide a workaround for Chrome?

Also: whether I do stopPropagation() or not does not seem to make any difference in either browser. Why is that?

Comment: please set up a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cd8hedju/